# Getting the number of similar rows in database and displaying them separately within a form

Tags: mysql, arrays, forms

I have a users table in a database, where the user enters a form into a database. This includes multiple radio buttons. I want it so the number of similar radio buttons is displayed next to the corresponding form entry.

There are 8 radio choices, and I have a working solution, although this is not ideal:

```
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $db) or die(mysql_error());

$query1 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream1' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

$query2 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream2' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

$query3 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream3' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());

$query4 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream4' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die(mysql_error());

$query5 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream5' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result5 = mysql_query($query5) or die(mysql_error());

$query6 = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE streamnumber = 'Stream6' GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result6 = mysql_query($query6) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have made a seperate query for each radio button, and then going to display information using this logic:

```
    <?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

                    echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(id)'] ." ". $row['streamnumber'] ." items.";
                    echo "<br />";


        } ?>
<input style="width:5px;" type="radio" name="streamnumber" value="Stream1" id="StreamDates_0">  
<label>Stream 1 - Module 1 + 2 - 21st - 23rd March, Module 3 - 19th - 20th April, Module 4 - 15th - 16th May 4</label>
```

This way I can use each count and name as the query specifies the streamnumber. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this? I assume this will be to do with a more complex array but I cant quite put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just run 1 query?

```
$query = "SELECT streamnumber, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM users 
 WHERE streamnumber IN ('Stream1', 'Stream2', 'Stream3',
 'Stream4', 'Stream5', 'Stream6') 
 GROUP BY streamnumber ORDER BY streamnumber "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$my_array=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
  $my_array[$row["streamnumber"]] = $row["cnt"];
}
// now $my_array["Stream1"] contains count of 'Stream1'
```

Comment: Yeah I had just one query before, but when echoing the results in a while loop, I couldnt specify which Streamnumber to get the name or count from. It just echoed it in a list, not at specific points in the form where I want bits displayed... does that make sense?

Comment: @JamesG: I think that even if you need to access results in different places, it's much better to query the server just once. After executing a query, you can iterate through it and store in array (key - streamnumber, value - count). Then you can access it like `$my_array["Stream4"]` in your code without sending extra requests

Comment: Yeah the key value pairs idea is exactly what I was after thanks. How would I access the value (count) from the array["Stream4"] though? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Like...$my_array["Stream4"][count]?

Comment: @JamesG : I updated my answer and added an example (note `COUNT(id) AS cnt` in query). Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. Looks easy when you put it like that lol. +1!!